# Show that $\inf\bigg(\big\{\frac{n}{n+1}|n\in\mathbb{N}\big\}\bigg)= \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Firstly I will show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a lower bound for the set. We have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

\begin{align}n\ge 1 \Longleftrightarrow n +n\ge 1+n \Longleftrightarrow 2n \ge 1+n \Longleftrightarrow \frac{n}{1+n} \ge \frac{1}{2}\end{align}

Now I am trying to show that $\frac{n}{n+1} < \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$. I have tried using the Archimedian property by manipulating $\epsilon > \dfrac{1}{n}$ in many ways but couldn't reach the result. I have also tried using contradiction by letting $\frac{n}{n+1} < m + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ for some $m > \frac{1}{2}$.

Any tips?

Comment: What can you say about the function $~1 - \dfrac{1}{x} ~: ~x > 1 ~?~$ That is, what can you say about this function, for various values of $~x,~$ restricted by $~x~$ being forced to be greater than $~1?~$  What is happening to this function, as $~x~$ increases?

Comment: Re last comment, suppose that $~f(x) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{x}.~$  Further suppose that $~x > 1.~$  Is $~f(x)~$ necessarily $~> 0~?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an element in the set that is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$. And this is indeed the case, because $\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$ is an element of the set, and it satisfies $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

In general, if a set has a minimum (i.e a lower bound that also belongs to the set, like $\frac{1}{2}$ in this example) then this minimum is the infimum of the set. The proof is precisely like in this example.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that, I have actually used the same reasoning on other problems.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\frac x{x+1}$ is an increasing function. To see this, re-write it as $1-\frac1{x+1}$ and note that $\frac1{x+1}$ is a decreasing function, so the original function is increasing. Now, the smallest number $x$ we could plug in here is $1$ so the smallest this function could be is $\frac12$. Therefore, the infimum of the set is just $\frac12$. No epsilon needed.